# files contain unwanted chars

Tags: java, file

I am having a weird problem in java with the BOM character `<feff>`. My code basically reads some data from DB stores it in a JSONArray, then changes its format to meet the format required by the server finally it writes it to a file.
This is how data currently is stored
`SYSTEM_ROLE|INSTITUTION_ROLE|ROW_STATUS|AVAILABLE_IND|EXTERNAL_PERSON_KEY|USER_ID|PASSWD|TITLE|FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|GENDER|COUNTRY|CITY|EMAIL|H_PHONE_1|M_PHONE|BIRTHDATE|JOB_TITLE|STUDENT_ID
<feff>none|P_Unified_Program|Enabled|Y|xxxxxx@xxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|Mr.|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|M|xxxxxx|xxxxxx (xxxxxx|xxxxxx@xxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|05/07/2000|(xxxxxx|xxxxxx
none|P_Unified_Program|Enabled|Y|xxxxxx@xxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|Mr.|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|M|xxxxxx|xxxxxx (xxxxxx)|xxxxxx@xxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|(xxxxxx|xxxxxx`

notice the char at the second row. The weird thing, that that char does not show up on the first row.
This is how I write the data to match the format required by the server

```
    public static String rawDBformat(JSONArray json, String[] columnsnames) {
    if (json.length() == 0 || columnsnames.length == 0) {
        logger.error("either the jsons' or the arrays' length passed to internaltoDBformat equal to zero " + json.toString());
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("either the strings' or the arrays' length passed to toDBformat equal to zero");
    }
    int numberofcolumns = columnsnames.length;
    String temp = "";
    String res = "";
    JSONObject jsonobj=null;
    jsonobj = json.getJSONObject(0);
    temp = jsonobj.getString(columnsnames[0]);
    for (int j = 1; j < numberofcolumns; j++) {
        temp += '|' + jsonobj.getString(columnsnames[j]);
    }
    res += temp + "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
        jsonobj = json.getJSONObject(i);
        temp = jsonobj.getString(columnsnames[0]);
        for (int j = 1; j < numberofcolumns; j++) {
            temp += '|' + jsonobj.getString(columnsnames[j]);
        }
        res += temp + "\n";
    }

    return res;
}
```

This is how I write to a file

```
    public static void writetofile(File file, String data) throws 
    IOException {
    OutputStreamWriter outputstream = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        logger.info("writing some data to " + 
    file.getCanonicalPath());
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        outputstream = new 
        OutputStreamWriter(fos,StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
        outputstream.write(data);
        fos.flush();
        outputstream.flush();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("An Exception occared", ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
            outputstream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("An Exception occared", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how both are used
`writetofile(assign, rawDBformat(res.json, res.columnsNames));`
`assign` is file, `res.json` is a JSONArray and `res.columnsNames` is a string array.

At the beginning I thought that the char was added in rawDBformat function so I tried `return res.substring(1);` but that did not work, it ended up returning the original data missing the first char. Also i noticed that the char gets added every time `writetofile` is called but not the first time which writes the header. Any idea how to solve this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF_16 does not specify a byte order, so a byte order mark is always generated to clarify which byte order is being written.

From the [documentation of Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html):

> The UTF-16 charsets use sixteen-bit quantities and are therefore sensitive to byte order. In these encodings the byte order of a stream may be indicated by an initial *byte-order mark* represented by the Unicode character `'\uFEFF'`. Byte-order marks are handled as follows:
>
> - When decoding, the `UTF-16BE` and `UTF-16LE` charsets interpret the initial byte-order marks as a `ZERO-WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE`; when encoding, they do not write byte-order marks.
> - When decoding, the `UTF-16` charset interprets the byte-order mark at the beginning of the input stream to indicate the byte-order of the stream but defaults to big-endian if there is no byte-order mark; **when encoding, it uses big-endian byte order and writes a big-endian byte-order mark.**

(Emphasis mine.)  StandardCharsets.UTF_16 does not specify a byte order, so its encoder (which is used by OutputStreamWriter) always writes a byte order mark before writing anything else.  To suppress it, use UTF_16BE or UTF_16LE instead.